# How to switch visibility of Android widget's UI element with button click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget

I'm trying to make a standalone Android widget with a button and an included layout visibility of which I would like to toggle with a button click

I was able to change visibility of my layout by sending pending intent

```
val V = Intent(context, ButtoWidget::class.java)
            V.action = ""
            V.putExtra("visibility", View.GONE)
            val pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,V,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

And used onRecieve to set the visibility.

```
if (intent.action == "") {

                for (appWidgetIds in appWidgetIds) {
                    val views = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.butto_widget)
                    
                    val myLayout = R.id.include

                        views.setViewVisibility(myLayout, View.VISIBLE)
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views)
            }
```

The problem is I can't figure out the correct if-statement to actually toggle the visibility. Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong.

I'm pretty new to all this so apologize if explanation is a bit messy. Could anyone help me with that?